# Is getop() implementation in K&R vulnerable to buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

The code of getop() - pag. 78 from K&R 2ed - is as follows:

```
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;
    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';

    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */

    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';

    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);

    return NUMBER;
}
```

(`getch` is just a wrapper to `getchar`, we can consider it to be the same)

Isn't that function vulnerable to buffer overflows? For example, when a user inputs a 20 long digit integer and `s` size is just 10, there is no size check whatsoever.

However, I cannot make the program crash, even when I define `s` to be size 2 and the input being a very very long 1111111...1111111, it just correctly give me `inf`.

Comment: **Yes**, writing potentially unlimited amount of characters into a fixed array counts as a buffer overflow. If you allocate `s` on the stack, you have to overrun it by a lot (~40) before interesting things start happening, if on the heap, at least a page (~4096). Try more digits.

Comment: The above estimates are only for a simple program that does nothing else, a complex program can crash and burn when you overrun by a single byte. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A buffer overflow results in undefined behaviour, that includes "not crashing".

In practice, the overflow causes modification of memory not part of the buffer.  Whether a crash results depends on what that memory is and how it is used. Often the overflow will corrupt adjacent variables, the function return address, and the stack frame of the calling function.  I'd the return address were corrupted, it would "crash" on function return, but you have no control over how the compiler organises memory usage.

For example, it is not uncommon in a debug build for some compilers to add stack padding to assist in error detection (in a debugger), so there may be a whole chunk of unused memory after the end of the buffer the modification of which will not cause a crash (but which a debugger may use to check for overflows).

Either way, you could use a debugger to inspect exactly what happens.  But certainly clearly it can overrun.

Comment: I used a debugger before posting the question and It certainly writes outside the scope of the array. However, I was surprised (and I still am) that no error was issued even when overflowing by 200 characters or more (maybe due to it being the last item pushed on  the stack or something like that). I won't investigate it further since we all agree that it overflows. Thanks!

Comment: @MrIo C is not required to perform runtime bounds checking, so would not issue an error.  As I said, the behaviour is dependent on what you corrupt.  An operating system may trap a "page fault" when a process accesses memory outside of its virtual memory space, but overrunning by just 200 bytes would not guarantee a page fault, and it is an operating system rather then a C runtime feature,   Besides your question was whether the buffer could overrun, not about whether or why there should be an error.  It sees that you already knew the answer to that and were possibly asking the wrong question.

Comment: @MrIo  What you might do in the debugger is observe the stack-pointer change on entry to the function (to see if it is adding padding), then enter sufficient characters to overrun the top of the stack frame containing the return address. The code will then likely crash when the function attempts to return.  You might also create and initialise a variable after the array, and observe its value changing when you overrun.  Still no runtime error would be reported, but any code dependent on the value of the corrupted variable would be affected.